# Appending lists with corresponding values from tibbles

Tags: r, list, lapply

Suppose my data is ordered as listed tibbles with a corresponding tibble that provides further info. Row "a" in infos refers thus to tibble "a" from the list.

```
list_in <- list(a=tibble(I=c(6:10),
                         II=c(2:6),
                         III=letters[1:5]),
                b=tibble(I=c(1:5),
                         II=c(2:6),
                         III=letters[2:6]),
                c=tibble(I=c(7:11),
                         II=c(3:7),
                         III=letters[5:9]))

infos <- tibble(id=c("a","b","c"),
                weights=c(1:3),
                grades=letters[4:6])
```

In order to do further calculations, is there a way to use `lapply` or a loop to append list_in, so that list_out also contains the corresponding values from `infos`? The expected output would look like this:

```
# install.packages("rlist")
library(rlist)

list_out <- list((list.append(list_in$a, weights=infos$weights[1], grades=infos$grades[1])),
              (list.append(list_in$b, weights=infos$weights[2], grades=infos$grades[2])),
              (list.append(list_in$c, weights=infos$weights[3], grades=infos$grades[3])))
```

but this way to get there feels very awkward and only works for very small data sets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and `c()` to append each tibble with the corresponding row of `infos`.

```r
list_out2 <- lapply(names(list_in), \(x) {
  c(list_in[[x]], infos[infos$id == x, -1])
})

all.equal(list_out, list_out2)
# [1] TRUE
```

```
list_out2

[[1]]
[[1]]$I
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

[[1]]$II
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

[[1]]$III
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

[[1]]$weights
[1] 1

[[1]]$grades
[1] "d"


[[2]]
[[2]]$I
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]$II
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

[[2]]$III
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

[[2]]$weights
[1] 2

[[2]]$grades
[1] "e"


[[3]]
[[3]]$I
[1]  7  8  9 10 11

[[3]]$II
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[3]]$III
[1] "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"

[[3]]$weights
[1] 3

[[3]]$grades
[1] "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left_join between the tibble in the list and the extra info:

```
append_info <- function(n) {
  out <- list_in[[n]] %>% 
    mutate(id = n) %>% 
    left_join(infos, by = 'id') %>% 
    select(-id)
  return(out)
}

lapply(names(list_in), append_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map`

```
Map(c, list_in, split(infos[-1], infos$id))
```

-output

```
$a
$a$I
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

$a$II
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

$a$III
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$a$weights
[1] 1

$a$grades
[1] "d"


$b
$b$I
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b$II
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

$b$III
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

$b$weights
[1] 2

$b$grades
[1] "e"

$c
$c$I
[1]  7  8  9 10 11

$c$II
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

$c$III
[1] "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"

$c$weights
[1] 3

$c$grades
[1] "f"
```